# Errors adding Environment Variables to NodeJS Elastic Beanstalk

Tags: amazon-web-services, nginx, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

My configuration worked up until yesterday. I have added the [nginx NodeJS https redirect extension from AWS](https://github.com/awslabs/elastic-beanstalk-samples/blob/master/configuration-files/aws-provided/security-configuration/https-redirect/nodejs/https-redirect-nodejs.config). Now, when I try to add a new Environment Variable through the Elastic Beanstalk configuration, I get this error:

```
[Instance: i-0364b59cca36774a0] Command failed on instance. Return code: 137 Output: + rm -f /etc/nginx/conf.d/00_elastic_beanstalk_proxy.conf + service nginx stop Stopping nginx: /sbin/service: line 66: 27395 Killed env -i PATH="$PATH" TERM="$TERM" "${SERVICEDIR}/${SERVICE}" ${OPTIONS}. Hook /opt/elasticbeanstalk/hooks/configdeploy/post/99_kill_default_nginx.sh failed. For more detail, check /var/log/eb-activity.log using console or EB CLI.
```

When I look at the eb-activity.log, I see this error:

```
[2018-02-18T17:24:58.762Z] INFO  [13848] - [Configuration update 1.0.61@112/ConfigDeployStage1/ConfigDeployPostHook/99_kill_default_nginx.sh] : Starting activity...
[2018-02-18T17:24:58.939Z] INFO  [13848] - [Configuration update 1.0.61@112/ConfigDeployStage1/ConfigDeployPostHook/99_kill_default_nginx.sh] : Activity execution failed, because: + rm -f /etc/nginx/conf.d/00_elastic_beanstalk_proxy.conf
  + service nginx stop
  Stopping nginx: /sbin/service: line 66: 14258 Killed                  env -i PATH="$PATH" TERM="$TERM" "${SERVICEDIR}/${SERVICE}" ${OPTIONS} (ElasticBeanstalk::ExternalInvocationError)
caused by: + rm -f /etc/nginx/conf.d/00_elastic_beanstalk_proxy.conf
  + service nginx stop
  Stopping nginx: /sbin/service: line 66: 14258 Killed                  env -i PATH="$PATH" TERM="$TERM" "${SERVICEDIR}/${SERVICE}" ${OPTIONS} (Executor::NonZeroExitStatus)
```

What am I doing wrong? And what has changed recently since this worked fine when I changed an Environment Variable a couple months ago.

Comment: Have you solved this problem in the end? I'm facing something similar, I'm just using the configuration like specified in the docs

Comment: Nope. Only way I can get around it is to push a new load without the 00_elastic_beanstalk_proxy.conf, rebuild the environment, change the variables and then put everything(00_elastic_beanstalk_proxy.conf) back.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I had this problem as well and Amazon acknowledged the error in the documentation.  This is a working restart script that you can use in your .ebextensions config file.

```
  /opt/elasticbeanstalk/hooks/configdeploy/post/99_kill_default_nginx.sh:
    mode: "000755"
    owner: root
    group: root
    content: |
      #!/bin/bash -xe
      rm -f /etc/nginx/conf.d/00_elastic_beanstalk_proxy.conf
      status=`/sbin/status nginx`

      if [[ $status = *"start/running"* ]]; then
        echo "stopping nginx..."
        stop nginx
        echo "starting nginx..."
        start nginx
      else
        echo "nginx is not running... starting it..."
        start nginx
      fi
```

Answer (score 1):

`service nginx stop` exits with status 137 (Killed).

Your script starts with: `#!/bin/bash -xe`

The parameter `-e` makes the script exit immediately whenever something exits with a non-zero  status.
If you want to continue the execution, you need to catch the exit status (137).

```
/opt/elasticbeanstalk/hooks/configdeploy/post/99_kill_default_nginx.sh:
    mode: "000755"
    owner: root
    group: root
    content: |
      #!/bin/bash -xe
      rm -f /etc/nginx/conf.d/00_elastic_beanstalk_proxy.conf
      status=`/sbin/status nginx`
      if [[ $status = *"start/running"* ]]; then
        set +e
        service nginx stop
        exitStatus = $?
        if [ $exitStatus -ne 0 ] && [ $exitStatus -ne 137 ]
        then
          exit $exitStatus
        fi
        set -e
      fi
      service nginx start
```

Answer (score 0):

The order of events looks like this to me:

1. Create a post-deploy hook to delete `/etc/nginx/conf.d/00_elastic_beanstalk_proxy.conf`
2. Run a container command to delete `/etc/nginx/conf.d/00_elastic_beanstalk_proxy.conf`
3. Run the post-deploy hook, which tries to delete `/etc/nginx/conf.d/00_elastic_beanstalk_proxy.conf`

So it doesn't seem surprising to me that the post-deploy script fails as the file you are trying to delete probably doesn't exist.

I would try one of two things:

1. Move the deletion of the temporary conf file from the container command to the `99_kill_default_nginx.sh` script, then remove the whole container command section.
2. Remove the line `rm -f /etc/nginx/conf.d/00_elastic_beanstalk_proxy.conf` from the `99_kill_default_nginx.sh` script.

Comment: Hmm. I tried both and it still failed. Any of the configurations (including the original) and everything is fine after I upload new code. But if I make ANY change to the configuration, the change fails and it goes back to the previous configuration.

Answer (score 0):

`/sbin/status nginx` seems not to work anymore. I updated the script to use `service nginx status`:

```yaml
  /opt/elasticbeanstalk/hooks/configdeploy/post/99_kill_default_nginx.sh:
    mode: "000755"
    owner: root
    group: root
    content: |
      #!/bin/bash -xe
      rm -f /etc/nginx/conf.d/00_elastic_beanstalk_proxy.conf
      status=$(service nginx status)

      if [[ "$status" =~ "running" ]]; then
        echo "stopping nginx..."
        stop nginx
        echo "starting nginx..."
        start nginx
      else
        echo "nginx is not running... starting it..."
        start nginx
      fi
```

And the faulty script is STILL in amazon's docs... I wonder when they are going to fix it. It's been enough time already